# How to convert complex Excel document to C# models

Tags: c#, epplus, import-from-excel

I'm having some trouble finding the ideal way to convert my Excel spreadsheet to C# models.

I've got some MVP code that's using the EPPlus library, but it's really simple in that it only opens the file and reads what's in the cells from top-left to bottom-right.

I'm looking for some guidance on the model structure that would be best for this kind of data, I think the code implementation should be straightforward once I can figure out a way of doing the models.

Would a model structure of something like this be ideal?

```cs
public class DataModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, Region> Regions { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public Dictionary<string, Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public Dictionary<string, Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
}

public class Subcategory
{
    public decimal UK { get; set; }
    public decimal England { get; set; }
    public decimal NorthEast { get; set; }
    public decimal NorthWest { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The Excel document looks something like this:

|  |  |  |  | UK | England | North East | North West | Yorkshire and the Humber | East Midlands | West Midlands | East | London | South East | South West | Wales | Scotland | Northern Ireland |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Food & non-alcoholic drinks |  |  | 60.30 | 60.80 | 55.20 | 56.40 | 54.40 | 61.20 | 58.00 | 62.20 | 65.80 | 66.20 | 61.00 | 56.10 | 57.00 | 63.80 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1.1 | Food |  |  | 55.30 | 55.80 | 50.30 | 51.80 | 49.90 | 56.00 | 53.00 | 57.10 | 60.60 | 61.00 | 56.10 | 51.60 | 51.60 | 58.00 |
|  | 1.1.1 | Bread, rice and cereals |  | 5.40 | 5.40 | 4.90 | 5.10 | 4.90 | 5.50 | 5.40 | 5.40 | 5.90 | 5.80 | 5.20 | 5.00 | 5.20 | 5.90 |
|  | 1.1.2 | Pasta products |  | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.50 | 0.50 |
|  | 1.1.3 | Buns, cakes, biscuits etc. |  | 3.80 | 3.80 | 3.70 | 3.60 | 3.30 | 4.00 | 3.80 | 3.90 | 3.90 | 4.10 | 4.10 | 3.50 | 3.70 | 4.60 |
|  | 1.1.4 | Pastry (savoury) |  | 0.90 | 0.90 | 0.90 | 0.90 | 0.90 | 1.00 | 0.80 | 1.00 | 0.90 | 1.00 | 0.90 | 0.90 | 0.90 | 0.90 |
| 1.2 | Non-alcoholic drinks |  |  | 5.00 | 5.00 | 4.90 | 4.50 | 4.40 | 5.20 | 5.00 | 5.10 | 5.30 | 5.20 | 4.80 | 4.50 | 5.50 | 5.80 |
|  | 1.2.1 | Coffee |  | 0.90 | 1.00 | 0.90 | 0.90 | 0.80 | 1.10 | 0.80 | 1.00 | 0.80 | 1.20 | 1.00 | 0.80 | 0.90 | 0.90 |
|  | 1.2.2 | Tea |  | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.60 |
|  | 1.2.3 | Cocoa and powdered chocolate |  | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 | 0.10 |
|  | 1.2.4 | Fruit and vegetable juices (inc. fruit squash) |  | 1.10 | 1.10 | 0.90 | 1.00 | 0.90 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.10 | 1.20 | 1.20 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 |
|  | 1.2.5 | Mineral or spring waters |  | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.30 | 0.40 | 0.30 | 0.30 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.70 | 0.40 | 0.30 | 0.40 | 0.30 | 0.50 |
|  | 1.2.6 | Soft drinks (inc. fizzy and ready to drink fruit drinks) |  | 2.00 | 2.00 | 2.30 | 1.80 | 1.90 | 2.10 | 2.20 | 2.00 | 1.90 | 1.80 | 1.90 | 2.00 | 2.70 | 2.70 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Alcoholic drink, tobacco & narcotics |  |  | 12.50 | 12.30 | 12.90 | 13.60 | 11.90 | 13.60 | 11.60 | 12.20 | 10.90 | 12.50 | 12.40 | 12.00 | 14.00 | 14.70 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2.1 | Alcoholic drinks |  |  | 8.70 | 8.80 | 8.20 | 9.50 | 8.30 | 9.30 | 8.20 | 8.90 | 7.90 | 9.10 | 9.10 | 8.10 | 8.50 | 7.70 |
|  | 2.1.1 | Spirits and liqueurs (brought home) |  | 2.00 | 1.90 | 2.20 | 1.90 | 1.50 | 2.30 | 1.90 | 2.10 | 1.60 | 1.80 | 1.90 | 2.00 | 2.50 | 2.00 |
|  | 2.1.2 | Wines, fortified wines (brought home) |  | 4.40 | 4.50 | 3.60 | 4.80 | 4.30 | 4.40 | 4.00 | 4.50 | 4.30 | 5.00 | 4.80 | 3.90 | 3.90 | 3.60 |
|  | 2.1.3 | Beer, lager, ciders and perry (brought home) |  | 2.30 | 2.30 | 2.30 | 2.80 | 2.50 | 2.60 | 2.30 | 2.20 | 2.00 | 2.20 | 2.40 | 2.20 | 2.00 | 2.00 |
|  | 2.1.4 | Alcopops (brought home) |  | 0.00~ | 0.00~ | [0.00~] | [0.00~] | [0.00~] | [0.00~] | 0.00~ | [0.00~] | .. | 0.00~ | [0.00~] | .. | 0.00~ | 0.00~ |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2.2 | Tobacco and narcotics |  |  | 3.80 | 3.50 | 4.70 | 4.00 | 3.60 | 4.30 | 3.50 | 3.30 | 3.00 | 3.40 | 3.30 | 3.90 | 5.50 | 7.00 |
|  | 2.2.1 | Cigarettes |  | 2.70 | 2.50 | 3.50 | 3.00 | 2.50 | 2.80 | 2.50 | 2.20 | 2.20 | 2.50 | 1.90 | 2.40 | 4.30 | 5.90 |
|  | 2.2.2 | Cigars, other tobacco products and narcotics |  | 1.10 | 1.10 | 1.20 | 1.00 | 1.10 | 1.50 | 0.90 | 1.10 | 0.70 | 0.90 | 1.40 | 1.50 | 1.20 | 1.10 |

Comment: The question is unclear and close to "Write the code for me".  EPPlus isn't an ORM, it's a library for creating Excel files. Excel isn't a database either, and what you posted isn't even a table but a hierarchical structure. Perhaps it was created by grouping? Or is it a PivotTable? You'll have to write the code that reads the lines, detects whether the line is a header, footer or detail, and fills the appropriate classes.

Comment: If that output is a grouped report or Pivot, you can use EPPlus to actually check for groupings, headers, footers.

Answer (score 1):

The model design is largely dependent on the way you will be accessing and doing further processing with your data so its hard to say what is the suitable data model for the dataset you provided.

From my perspective though, you can create a Tree-like structure in this case

```
public class Node
{
    public Node ParentNode { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> Values { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NodeAlternativeData { get; set; }
}
```

Example construction

```
var rootNode = new Node()
{
    Name = "Food & non-alcoholic drinks",
    Values = new Dictionary<string, double>()
    {
        {"UK",1}, {"England", 2}
    },
    ParentNode = null,
    NodeAlternativeData = "1"
};

var foodNode = new Node()
{
    Name = "Food",
    Values = new Dictionary<string, double>()
    {
        {"UK",1}, {"England", 2}
    },
    ParentNode = rootNode,
    NodeAlternativeData = "1.1"
};

var drinkNode = new Node()
{
    Name = "Drink",
    Values = new Dictionary<string, double>()
    {
        {"UK",1}, {"England", 2}
    },
    ParentNode = rootNode,
    NodeAlternativeData = "1.2"
};
```